# Koch snowflake in Python with Turtle

Tags: python, fractals, turtle-graphics

After finding [a piece of code on StackOverflow that drew the Koch snowflake fractal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534115/koch-snowflake-rendering-time-and-how-to-draw-a-snowflake-using-turtle), I made a ton of modifications to it and used it to produce an animation divided in two parts:

- Constant size, recursion depth increasing.
- Constant recursion depth, size increasing.

[You can see the animation here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RljwD1mVX6Y)

I am interested mainly in:

- Have I got too many constants? I like them because they make the program easy to customize, but 12 constants looks like a lot.
- Any idea to avoid repetition in these blocks of code?

  ```
  write_as_title(\
      "Constant size, recursion depth increasing.", font=FONT)
  time.sleep(WRITING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL)

  for deepness in range(MAX_DEPTH):
      costum_reset()
      snowflake(deepness, SIZE_WHEN_CONSTANT_DEPTH)
      time.sleep(DRAWING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL)
  ```

  ```
  costum_reset()
  write_as_title(\
      "Constant recursion depth, size increasing.", font=FONT)
  time.sleep(WRITING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL)
  for size in RANGE_OF_SIZES:
      costum_reset()
      snowflake(DEPTH_WHEN_CONSTANT_SIZE, size)
  ```

  They are similar but I cannot quite abstract the similarity out.

---

```
from __future__ import division

import turtle
import time

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
FONT = ("Arial", 25, "normal")
DRAWING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL = 0.5
WRITING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL = 2.5
MAX_DEPTH = 5
SIZE_WHEN_CONSTANT_DEPTH = 300
DEPTH_WHEN_CONSTANT_SIZE = 4
RANGE_OF_SIZES = range(0, 5000, 5)
SIDES_OF_AN_EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE = 3
EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE_INTERNAL_ANGLE = 120
DRAWING_START_X = - 200
DRAWING_START_Y = 150

def snowflake(n, size=300):

    for _ in range(SIDES_OF_AN_EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE):
        snowflake_edge(n, size)
        turtle.right(EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE_INTERNAL_ANGLE)

    turtle.update()

def snowflake_edge(n, size=300):
    if n == 0:
        turtle.forward(size)
        return

    for movement in (lambda: turtle.left(EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE_INTERNAL_ANGLE // 2),
                   lambda: turtle.right(EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE_INTERNAL_ANGLE),
                   lambda: turtle.left(EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE_INTERNAL_ANGLE // 2)):
        snowflake_edge(n - 1, size / SIDES_OF_AN_EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE)
        movement()

    snowflake_edge(n - 1, size / SIDES_OF_AN_EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE)

def costum_reset():
    turtle.reset()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx( DRAWING_START_X )
    turtle.sety( DRAWING_START_Y )
    turtle.pendown()

def write_as_title(title, font=FONT):
    turtle.setx(- (WIDTH // 2.5) )
    turtle.sety(HEIGHT // 3)
    turtle.write(title, font=font)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    turtle.setup(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.tracer(0, 0)

    write_as_title(\
        "Constant size, recursion depth increasing.", font=FONT)
    time.sleep(WRITING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL)

    for deepness in range(MAX_DEPTH):
        costum_reset()
        snowflake(deepness, SIZE_WHEN_CONSTANT_DEPTH)
        time.sleep(DRAWING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL)

    costum_reset()
    write_as_title(\
        "Constant recursion depth, size increasing.", font=FONT)
    time.sleep(WRITING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL)
    for size in RANGE_OF_SIZES:
        costum_reset()
        snowflake(DEPTH_WHEN_CONSTANT_SIZE, size)
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code reads well and is easily understandable. On top of also finding that you might have too much constant (more on that in a little bit), I just have a few nitpicks:

- [whitespace in expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) is weird sometimes;
- a docstring would help understanding the recursion involved in `snowflake_edge`;
- you don't need the newline continuation (`\`) inside parenthesis, they already act as an implicit one;
- you allow to parametrize `write_as_title` with a custom font but nothing similar is done with other kind of parameters.

## On reducing the similarities between the two drawings

I would have put a call to `costum_reset` (costum? really?) at the beginning of both `write_as_title` and `snowflake` since both drawings need a clear state to begin with.

I would also put `time.sleep(WRITING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL)` at the end of `write_as_title`. Considering its value, it won't hurt anyone in an interactive session and is still needed in a program for people to be able to read the text.

This way, the main part would look like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    turtle.setup(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.tracer(0, 0)

    write_as_title(
        "Constant size, recursion depth increasing.", font=FONT)    
    for deepness in range(MAX_DEPTH):
        snowflake(deepness, SIZE_WHEN_CONSTANT_DEPTH)
        time.sleep(DRAWING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL)

    write_as_title(
        "Constant recursion depth, size increasing.", font=FONT)
    for size in RANGE_OF_SIZES:
        snowflake(DEPTH_WHEN_CONSTANT_SIZE, size)
```

You can even make the two sensible parts two functions if you want to separate the concerns better.

## On reducing the amount of constants

Of your 12 constants, a few are really constant, some are arbitrary fixed for the purpose of your application, and some could be tweaked to achieve a better (prettier?) result.

Maybe that allowing to change the latter group using the command line could be more intuitive to tweak the parameters of the display. I personally would keep the following constants:

- `WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600`
- `FONT = ("Arial", 25, "normal")`
- `WRITING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL = 2.5`
- `SIDES_OF_AN_EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE = 3`
- `EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE_INTERNAL_ANGLE = 120`
- `DRAWING_START_X = - 200`
- `DRAWING_START_Y = 150`

And use `argparse` to provide default values or custom ones from the command line for:

- `DRAWING_SLEEPING_INTERVAL`
- `MAX_DEPTH`
- `SIZE_WHEN_CONSTANT_DEPTH`
- `DEPTH_WHEN_CONSTANT_SIZE`
- `SIZES_LIMIT`

Note the use of `SIZES_LIMIT` which will then create the range object `RANGE_OF_SIZES`.

All of these last "constants" are only used within the `if __name__ == '__main__'` so it's pretty easy to adapt.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at this function:

```
def snowflake(n, size=300):
    for _ in range(SIDES_OF_AN_EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE):
        snowflake_edge(n, size)
        turtle.right(EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE_INTERNAL_ANGLE)
    turtle.update()
```

1. There's no docstring. What does it do? What is the meaning of the arguments?
2. The name `n` does not give much of a clue. I would call this argument `depth`.
3. The function does two things: it draws the snowflake, and it updates the screen. It is usually best if a function does just one thing: then you have more flexibility about how you use it. For example, what if you wanted to draw several snowflakes before updating the screen?
4. The constant `EQUILATERAL_TRIANGLE_INTERNAL_ANGLE` is wrongly named. It has the value 120, but the interior angle of an equilateral triangle is actually 60°. The term you want here is *exterior angle*.
5. The function uses two constants, but these are not independent. The exterior angle \$θ\$ of a regular polygon can be computed from the number of sides \$k\$, like this: \$θ = {360°\over k}\$.
6. One way to reduce the number of constants is to turn them into function parameters. I would write:

   ```
   # Number of degrees in a full circle.
   FULLCIRCLE = 360

   def snowflake(depth=4, size=300, sides=3):
       """Draw a Koch snowflake fractal.

       Arguments:
       depth -- depth of recursion.
       size -- length of each side, in pixels.
       sides -- number of sides of the snowflake.

       """
       theta = FULLCIRCLE / sides
       for _ in range(sides):
           snowflake_edge(depth, size)
           turtle.right(theta)
   ```

   (A global constant for the number of degrees in a full circle is necessary, unfortunately, because Turtle allows you to change this using the [`degrees`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.degrees) function, but doesn't have a documented way of getting the current value.)